# On Solaris, how do you mount a second zfs system disk for diagnostics?

Tags: solaris, mount, opensolaris, zfs

I've got two hard disks in my computer, and have installed Solaris 10u8 on the first and Opensolaris 2010.3 (dev onnv_134) on the second.  Both systems uses ZFS and were independently created with a zpool name of 'rpool'.

While running Solaris 10u8 on the first disk, how do I mount the second ZFS hard disk (at /dev/dsk/c1d1s0) on an arbitrary mount point (like /a) for diagnostics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have upgraded your OpenSolaris zpool to a newer version, for example to take advantage of deduplication, you won't be able to do it.

If there is no version issue, you can use that command:

```
zpool import -f -R /a 3347820847789110672 oldrpool
```

Replace *3347820847789110672* (pool id) by the one displayed with "zpool import" with no other options.

If you need to mount the pool for diagnostic purposes, better to boot on a CD that contains the latest OpenSolaris distribution.